# How to show "game over" when the Countdown is over in google sheets

Tags: performance, google-sheets, time, timer, countdown

I have added the COUNTDOWN timer to my google sheet by the code that comes below, when the time is over the value gets negative and it shows "#NUM!". I want it to show "GAME OVER!" when the time is up.

=int(B6-now())&" "&if(days(B6,now())>1,"Days","Day")&" : "&hour(B6-now())&" "&if(hour(B6-now())>1,"Hours","Hour")&" : "&MINUTE(B6-now())&" "&if(MINUTE(B6-now())>1,"Minutes","Minute",if(($B6-now())<0,"COMPLETE"))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when the countdown is over, it shows "Error Function HOUR parameter 1 value is negative. It should be positive or zero." in the googlesheets cell
 BUT I want it to show "gameover"

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IFERROR(int(B6-now())&" "&if(days(B6,now())>1,"Days","Day")&" : "&hour(B6-now())&" "&if(hour(B6-now())>1,"Hours","Hour")&" : "&MINUTE(B6-now())&" "&if(MINUTE(B6-now())>1,"Minutes","Minute",if(($B6-now())<0,"COMPLETE")), "Game Over")
```